# FBFriendPickerViewController for iOS 7 doesn't work as expected in landscape mode

Tags: facebook, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working for Facebook integration in my iPad app. I am using **FBFriendPickerViewController** for same. My app is working fine on iOS 6 for landscape as well as portrait mode but when I use iOS 7 then friend picker controller works fine ONLY for portrait. When try to launch it in landscape mode then white view pops up. I could see faint friend picker view in background but very hard to see that. Do anyone have any idea what must be the reason? Code base I have used is as below.

```
 if (!_friendPicker) {
            self.friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
           // _friendPicker.delegate = self;
            _friendPicker.title = @"Select a friend";
            _friendPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = NO; // Share dialog doesn't allow more than one recipient
        }


        [_friendPicker clearSelection];
        [_friendPicker loadData];
        _friendPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;            
        [_friendPicker presentModallyFromViewController:self
                                                        animated:YES
                                               handler:nil];
```

Same thing I have observed on facebook sample app "HelloFacebookSample" :)

Comment: I am experiencing the same exact issue.  It was fully functional under iOS6 in landscape.  My function syntax doesn't vary much from above either so I am wondering if it is an issue with the friendpicker class itself?

Comment: Yes i think so, coz i tried so many thinks but didn't get success

Comment: I filed a bug report with Facebook. We might be waiting awhile so probably best to start looking at alternatives.

Comment: Hey.. Thanks Doug. Please post once you receive any feedback from Facebook

Comment: Incidentally, if anyone else comes across the issue, the Facebook bug report is: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/605086346220205  Please add to it.

Comment: It seems like this is related to their handling of the status bar in the SDK, I found that turning it off in the presenting view controller seems to work around this problem. Just make sure you have a method like this one :

`- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Get the **newest Facebook SDK**, because in the above link a Facebook rep says the issue should be resolved. The modal frame still takes into account the space for the status bar so you'll have to find a way to deal with it (doesn't bother me enough to spend time solving it at this point).
2. I also removed a `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:];` line from my app delegate, so maybe try removing all nav bar customisation and see what you get.

Good luck.